# Need to implement html button to access REST get resource

Tags: javascript, html, rest

Fairly new to REST and web application and would like to create a front-end site with a button and a place where a result is displayed.

I have REST API structured like this: 
http://hostserver.com/MEApp/MEService

This returns a value when browsing to it.

Now I would like to implement a GUI so that when you browse to c:\resourcebutton.html
There will be a button and when I click on it, it will call the REST API resource and returns the result. If I understood REST correctly it should work like this.

I have a html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

How and where should I insert the GET method to call the API? Is it common to use Javascript?

Comment: AJAX, is what you are looking for. You can use for instance [jQuery's ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Is it not possible to do this with html and javascript? Since I am more familiar with these technology..

Comment: `Ajax` IS Javascript. Ajax means "Asynchronous Javascript Request" and is basically just the name for a HTTP-Request, which is perfomed with the help of JavaScript. Without Ajax, your browser needs to refresh the page everytime you want to load something from a server.

Comment: @maja Ajax seemed to be working well with XML and SOAP. But I'm working with RESTEasy web service and would like to learn and consume that resource.

Comment: @JustinBieber Ajax is used to perform an HTTP-Request. You can download everything from HTML, XML, JSON, JPG, MP4 or even the whole Internet. As long as you offer the correct Url, the correct Method (Post, Get, ...) and the correct Parameters, it works.

Comment: Unfortunately, the link you provided doesn't work, so I don't know anything about the Rest-Service you're using

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to do this with JavaScript. In fact, you need Ajax.

To simplify things, you should download and include JQuery to your site, and then use something like this:

```
$.post( "http://hostserver.com/MEApp/MEService", function( data ) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
  //Or, in the JQuery-way:
  $('#demo').html(data);
});
```

The jQuery Source can be found here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js

Your html-file would then look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="the/Path/To/The/Downloaded/JQuery.js"></script>
    <script>
        //Usually, you put script-tags into the head
        function myFunction() {
            //This performs a POST-Request.
            //Use "$.get();" in order to perform a GET-Request (you have to take a look in the rest-API-documentation, if you're unsure what you need)
            //The Browser downloads the webpage from the given url, and returns the data.
            $.post( "http://hostserver.com/MEApp/MEService", function( data ) {
                 //As soon as the browser finished downloading, this function is called.
                 $('#demo').html(data);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just read a bit about jQuery. It's a further work on javascript right? And in your code you used $.post .... ); This block is jQuery I think, since I'm new to jQuery. 

It seemed like a very nice solution but it might be an overwork for me since I'm just starting to learn how it works and looking to understand how I should format a button that calls the rest resource and displays the result. 
Thanks

Comment: Yes. It's a JavaScript-Library which provides lots of cross-browser compatible functions, which makes life much easier. JQuery is used on many sites in the Internet, and I recommend using it in every JavaScript-Project

Comment: @JustinBieber See my updated example. Modifying the HTML is also much easier with JQuery.

Comment: I am totally new to web applications and looking to understand the interaction between REST api and the web gui.. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

$.post( "http://hostserver.com/MEApp/MEService", function( data ) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = data;
  //Or, in the JQuery-way:
  $('#demo').html(data);
});

</body>
</html>

You mean like this?

Comment: I would need to use GET in my case since there is only GET method implemented in the service. It goes like this: 
 @Path("/MEService")
 public class MEService {
  @GET()
  //@Path("/")
  @Produces("text/plain")
  public String getServiceInfo() {
   return "50";
  }

  
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55895/discussion-between-justinbieber-and-maja).