# How to make a REST call using jquery's $ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am using the answer given on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302263/need-to-implement-html-button-to-access-rest-get-resource/24302353#24302353).
As a result, my html page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="path\jquery-2.1.1"></script>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert('Clicked!');
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:51399/api/webapi",
                type: 'GET',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data.error);
                    $('#demo').html(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button nothing happens. I am not sure if the ajax call is ever made or if there is no success on the callback. What am I missing and how can I fix it so that the GET REST call goes through to the URL I specified?

P.S.: I am a beginner at javascript and jquery.

Comment: Open up your console and check for errors, also check the network tab and see what the status of the request is.

Comment: I also recommend to read the documentation and have a look at the examples there: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/. Better yet, read the jQuery **tutorial**: http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: i did read the documentation. i had all the parameters like dataType etc. in my call but the same issue existed with that too.

Comment: jsfiddle has a special way it expects/responds to AJAX requests. If you're testing there, be sure your using the correct URLs. http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wold's answer above is completely valid. However, the issue with my code was that I was trying to reference the jquery.js file using its absolute path which is prohibited. Once I made the path relative (and added the extension...stupid me) the call went through.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://blockchain.info/latestblock",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function(data) {
            $('#demo').html(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error: " + errorThrown + " || status: " + textStatus + " || data: " + jqXHR);
        }
});
```

or (the more modern way):

```
function myFunction(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://blockchain.info/latestblock",
    type: 'GET'
  });
}

function handleData(data) {
  $('#demo').html(data);
}

function handleError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("error: " + errorThrown + " || status: " + textStatus + " || data: " + jqXHR);
}

myFunction().fail(handleError)
myFunction().done(handleData);
```

Comment: I added your code to the page. Still no response. Here's the JSFiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/BFnL5/7/

Comment: well this is a whole other issue: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://blockchain.info/latestblock. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access"

Comment: Ahh that should explain the issue. I can try running a local webapi and see if this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, running a simple WebApi on localhost still yields no result. Note that I run the code locally and not through JSFiddle. I tried looking for an example out there that simply makes a REST GET call to any API. But I found no results.

Comment: But there was no console error? i would recommend adding an error parameter to the settings array to check if there is a server error with the request.

Comment: try it now (but I would recommend the first method)

Comment: @ritratt: Access to an endpoint on the same machine but a different port is still subject to the same origin policy.